# Laravel 5.5 query (sub-query) pluck

Tags: laravel, eloquent, subquery

Please,

I have:

Tables:

- ads
- ad_settings
- special_sections

table: ads (among others):

- id (9)
- title

table: ads_settings (among others):

- id (45)
- ad_id (9)
- is_active

table: special_sections (among others):

- id (1)
- ad_setting_id (45)
- name

**In my controller I have:**

```
$ad = AdSetting::with(["ad" => function($q){
    $q->where('ad_id', '=', 'id');
}])->pluck('ad_id', 'id' );
```

The above gives me:

```
Collection {#14946 ▼
  #items: array:14 [▼
    9 => 45
  ]
}
```

dd($ad) gives me the "ad id" (9) and the "ad_setting id" (45)

I'm struggling to pluck the ad_setting id (45) with the **ad title**. Do I need another (inner) query?

I'm really confused now, can someone please give some advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would need to see more code to see what your model looks like but I will assume you have a model named `AdSetting` where you have a relationship defined like so:

```
public function ad() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Ad');
}
```

In order to retrieve all your add settings with their respective ad titles, you can do something like this:

```
$ads = AdSetting::with('ad')->get()->pluck('ad.title', 'id');
```

This should give you a collection of all your Ad Settings where the key is equal to the AdSetting's id column and the result shall be the title of the ad.

```
[
    1 => 'ad title',
    2 => 'some other ad title',
    //...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ad = AdSetting::with(["ad" => function($q){
    $q->where('ad_id', '=', 'id');
}])->get(['ad_id', 'id', 'title']); // you can only selects 'ads_settings' column
```

if you declare relations between `ad` and `ad_settings` (not sure which type of relations. I assume that is `hasMany` <-> `belongsTo`)

> you have to look into what relation is at [document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships)

you can simple do

```
$ad = AdSettings::with('ad')
    ->get(['ad_id', 'id', 'title'])
    ->toArray();
```